# Is it possible to build an expo app locally without having an account?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I see here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/ that in order to build my expo app on my own infrastructure, I need to have expo

> - Company policies that restrict the use of third-party CI/CD services. With local builds, the entire process runs on your infrastructure and the only communication with EAS servers is:
>
>   - to make sure project @account/slug exists
>   - if you are using managed credentials to download them.
> - Debugging (more info in the next section)

Is there a way to build my apps (iOS and Android) without having to be logged in to Expo servers in any way?

Answer (score -1):

They finally added the answer to their documentation:

```bash
eas build --platform android --local
eas build --platform ios --local
```

https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/ (watched August 29th 2023)

Comment: You are still reqired to login to your expo account to build it locally

Answer (score -1):

Expo's features and policies can change over time, so I recommend checking the official Expo documentation or website for the most up-to-date information regarding account requirements and features.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).